# React Native can't build the sample project (XCode 8.1 / Sierra)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I just tried building the sample project for React-Native and I am getting the following error:

```
The following build commands failed:
    Libtool /Users/computerName/project/react-native/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTSettings.a normal x86_64
    Libtool /Users/computerName/project/react-native/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTVibration.a normal x86_64
    Libtool /Users/computerName/project/react-native/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTLinking.a normal x86_64
(3 failures)
Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject.app
No devices are booted.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

I've tried removing `node_modules` and doing a reinstall.

I am running the following react and react-native-versions

```
"react": "15.3.2",
"react-native": "0.36.0"
```

I also killed all processes that were running on `localhost:8081`

Edit: I got it working by downloading the old ios 8.1 simulator and setting it manually in Xcode:

[image: Set simulator to ios 8.1]

Answer (score 1):

You have to open this project using `xCode` and check in `general` tab if `Bundle Identifier` is set (if not write something like `com.myawesomeproject`)

[image]

Comment: it was set to $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)

Answer (score 0):

```
ANISHs-MacBook-Air:watchman anishsnair$ ./autogen.sh 
./autogen.sh: line 9: aclocal: command not found
./autogen.sh: line 10: autoheader: command not found
./autogen.sh: line 11: automake: command not found
./autogen.sh: line 12: autoconf: command not found
```

Comment: Please include some explanation/context as this makes the answer more useful for others.